# python - multi folders with nested structure

Tags: python, unix

How to create a multi folders with nested structure in python api in a simple way with out loops like unix command `mkdir -p a/b/c/{d,e,f}`
seems like `pathlib` or `os.mkdirs` has no direct provision for this.

Tried in this way `pathlib.Path(dest).mkdir(0o755, parents=True, exist_ok=True)` but not working

Comment: Is the ```dest``` argument to ```Path()``` actually ```"a/b/c/{d,e,f}"``` ? ```pathlib``` doesn't do brace expansion like shells do.

Comment: exactly is there any smarter way to achieve this like with out writing lot of code?

Comment: You could try ```braceexpand``` as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38485954/13843268). Other than that, you probably have to craft each path to pass to ```pathlib``` or use something like ```subprocess``` to execute the ```mkdir``` command as you would on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in Python with Pathlib and a simple for loop

```
from pathlib import Path

base = Path("a/b/c")

for child in ['d', 'e', 'f']:
    (base / Path(child)).mkdir(mode=0o755, parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

dest = Path('a/b/c')
subdirs = ['d', 'e', 'f']

[(dest / subdir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) for subdir in subdirs]
```