# How to write "or" in a glob() pattern?

Tags: python, glob

`glob.glob()` does not use regex. it uses Unix path expansion rules. How can I emulate this regex in glob:

```
".*.jpg|.*.png"
```

Comment: ```.*.{jpg,png}``` would be valid in a shell, but glob doesn't support that. But see this question for a workaround: [Brace expansion in python glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996645/brace-expansion-in-python-glob)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@U12-Forward is correct that there isn't an exact solution but depending on your use case you might be able to solve it with the `[...]` wildcard. For your example with `.png` or `.jpg` you could use this:

```
.*.[jp]*
```

which will match any extension that starts with a j or p

If you have other extensions that start with j or p you can be more specific:

```
.*.[jp][pn]g
```

Answer (score 14):

Well, with `glob` you should just do this:

```
lst = glob.glob('*.jpg') + glob.glob('*.png')
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am actually looking for a more elegant way. This will look like this if I use the pathlib module since its glob() method returns a generator object:

lst = list(pathlib.Path.glob('*.jpg')) + list(pathlib.Path.glob('*.png'))

Comment: @alzoubi36 Yeah, that's the way, there isn't any more elegent solution unfortunately, feel free to mark and vote this if you like :)

Comment: I voted up for the effort, but I won't mark it since I knew this solution. @U12-Forward

Comment: @alzoubi36 Well, this is the *only* one :)