# How to get a list of all filenames with ".fits" extension in directory?

Tags: python

I have a directory full of files of several different types (.fits, .jpg, .txt, etc.). I want to create a list that contains strings of only all the .fits filenames in the directory. Is there a convenient way to write this in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write "or" in a glob() pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298452/how-to-write-or-in-a-glob-pattern)

Comment: `files = pathlib.Path(yourpathnamehere).glob('*.fits')`...?