# Ansible: how to include a task file specified by an environment variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a folder containing a list of named tasks-files and want to include them based on a specific selector.

Eg.

```
inventory_dir
| stacks
  | tasks
    | app1.yml
    | app2.yml
    | app3.yml
```

The Selector can be a list, and can contain elements that doesn't have a taskfile.

I'm trying different approaches to reach my goal, but

```yaml
- name: tentative 1
  block:
  - name: Tasks to execute always
    include_tasks: ./generic-tasks.yml
  - name: Include specific tasks for specific selector
    include_tasks:
      file: "{{ inventory_dir }}/stacks/tasks/{{ item }}.yml"
    loop: 
    - '{{ SELECTOR }}'
```

Here I cannot use a stat task, because I don't know in advance what is the value of {{ item }} (and I cannot loop over a block). So this will fail in case the selector doesn't have a taskfile.

To avoid this I tried to do the contrary: looping over the folder content, and filtering by selector.

```yaml
  - name: Include specific tasks for specific selector
    include_tasks:
      file: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', '{{ inventory_dir }}/stacks/tasks/*.yml',wantlist=True) }}"
    when: "item|regex_replace("(?:\/[ \w]+){1,}\/([ \w]+)(?:\.yml)", "\1") in SELECTOR"
```

But it fail, probably because of the "in" check failing. (The regexp is working correctly anyway).

Do you have a better strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using a separate task-file.

main.yml

```yaml
- name: tentative 1
  block:
  - name: Tasks to execute always
    include_tasks: ./generic-tasks.yml
  - name: Include specific tasks for specific selector
    include_tasks:
      file: "specific-tasks.yml"
    loop: 
    - '{{ SELECTOR }}'
```

specific-tasks.yml

```yaml
  - name: Check for file existence
    stat:
      path: "{{ inventory_dir }}/stacks/tasks/{{item}}.yml"
    register: "taskfile"
    delegate_to: localhost
    become: false

  - name: Include tasks specific to this stack
    include_tasks:
      file: "{{ inventory_dir }}/stacks/tasks/{{ item }}.yml"
    when: "taskfile.stat.exists"

  - name: Unregister taskfile
    set_fact:
      taskfile: ''
```

I'm still posting this in case there are better strategies

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) and put it inside a block. This will fit on a single include level.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    include_file_list: >
      {{ (SELECTOR | d([], true)) | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '\1.yml') }}

  tasks:
    - when: include_file_list | length > 0
      block:

        - name: check which files exist based on selector
          find:
            paths:
              - '{{ inventory_dir }}'
            patterns: "{{ include_file_list }}"
          register: check_task_files

        - name: include existing task files
          include_tasks: "{{ item.path }}"
          loop: "{{ check_task_files.files }}"
```

Meanwhile, note that this will basically only succeed when targeting localhost as `find` runs on the target host. If you ever run this on a remote target you might get errors because either:

- the inventory dir does not exist on the target
- a file found on the target does not exist on the controller

So although a bit more complicated to read/understand, the following which will only look for files on the controller using the [`fileglob` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html) is more appropriate.

The template expression to aggregate found files is needed because [python glob does not understand the curly braces notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996645/brace-expansion-in-python-glob) and we need to expand and search for each possible path ourselves. (i.e. `/some/path/{a,b,c}.yml` will not return any matches)

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    include_file_list: >
      {{ (SELECTOR | d([], true)) | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', inventory_dir ~ '/stacks/tasks/\1.yml') }}
    found_files: >
      {%- set found = [] -%}
      {%- for path in include_file_list -%}
      {{ found.append(q('fileglob', path)) }}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ found | flatten}}

  tasks:
    - name: include existing files
      include_tasks: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ found_files }}"
```